# In c++, what is the best style for endian conversion

Tags: c++

I am making a library of inline functions for dealing with testing platform endianness and doing conversions..

My first attempt was to structure the functions like this:

```
inline uint32_t NativeToLittle(uint32_t in)
{
    if(littleEndian())
        return in;
    else
    {
        uint32_t var = 0;
        ((uint16_t*)&var)[0] = NativeToLittle(((uint16_t*)&in)[1]);
        ((uint16_t*)&var)[1] = NativeToLittle(((uint16_t*)&in)[0]);

        return var; 
    }
}
```

This worked on some platforms, but on gcc with aggressive optimisation options, it fails (casting uint32_t* to uint16_t* ran afoul of the strict aliasing rules.)

Given that the aliasing rules make a mention of unions, I rewrote the functions to use unions for conversion, like this:

```
inline uint32_t swapEndian(uint32_t in)
{
    union ds
    {
        uint32_t a;
        uint16_t b[2];
    };

    ds var;
    ds out;
    var.a = in;
    out.b[0] = swapEndian(var.b[1]);
    out.b[1] = swapEndian(var.b[0]);

    return out.a;
}
```

This worked on all platforms I've tried it on, but I'm not clear about whether it's good style. I recall seeing a video where the speaker said that this scheme of using unions for conversions was invalid because it was only valid to access one member of a union (I don't recall the url of this talk, sorry). Moreover, Stroustrup's JSF coding standards states that "unions shall not be used".

The only other relevant thing in the aliasing rules is that casting to a char type is valid. Converting it to a char buffer and back is likely to be pretty ugly, though.

So.. What is the best way to structure code like this which is both consistent with the standard and reasonably readable?

Comment: The union trick is indeed UB (you may not read a member other than the one last written to). Use bit shifts etc.

Comment: Take a look at how Boost Endian does it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
inline uint32_t swapEndian(uint32_t in)
{
    return (in >> 24) &  0xFF         |   //move byte 3 to byte 0
           (in >> 8)  & (0xFF << 8)   |   //move byte 2 to byte 1
           (in << 8)  & (0xFF << 16)  |   //move byte 1 to byte 2
           (in << 24) & (0xFF << 24); |   //move byte 0 to byte 1
}
```

Comment: This does a different conversion to OP's code  (not clear whether he intended that)

Comment: Well I've never heard of a platform that does endianness by 2-byte increments. If that's really what OP wants then it simplifies to `(in >> 16) & 0xFFFF | (in << 16) & (0xFFFF << 16)`

Comment: `0xFFFF` is signed so you mean `(in >> 16) | ((in & 0xFFFF) << 16)`

Comment: Well, I've actually overloaded swapEndian for different sized ints, but I thought it'd be too verbose to include them all in the post. The 64 bit function calls the 32 bit function on its two sub-parts, which in turn calls the 16 bit version of the function..

Comment: Oh, I see. Then I guess you do `(in >> 8) & 0xFF | (in & 0xFF << 8)` for the 16-bit, and `(v[1] >> 16) & 0xFFFF | (v[0] & 0xFF << 8)` for the 32-bit, etc.

Comment: Although my way saves a bit of processing power since you're only moving each byte once. Could add up if you're doing this many times)

Comment: How does this 'swapEndian()' function do nothing for the case where host order does _not_ need rearranging?

Answer (score 1):

It's awful. You should almost never check for the endianness of the processor. And if you do conversions, you should convert from an array of bytes in external format to your internal format, or from your internal format to an array of bytes in external format.

Your function is from the very start misleading. The "in" parameter isn't really a uint32_t to start with. You should write something like

```
uint32_t readExternalInt (unsigned char* p) {
    return (p [aaa] << 24)  | (p [bbb] << 16) | (p [ccc] << 8) | p [ddd];
}
```

with appropriate values for aaa, bbb, ccc and ddd. See how much shorter this is? And it works on every processor, whether bigendian, littleendian, mixedendian, upside down, standing on its head, or whatever.

Answer (score 1):

As much as I dislike macro's, a reasonable solution is from the network code

For example, using man htons:

```
Linux Programmer's Manual 

NAME
   htonl,  htons,  ntohl,  ntohs - convert values between host and network
   byte order

SYNOPSIS
   #include <arpa/inet.h>

   uint32_t htonl(uint32_t hostlong);

   uint16_t htons(uint16_t hostshort);

   uint32_t ntohl(uint32_t netlong);

   uint16_t ntohs(uint16_t netshort);

DESCRIPTION
   The htonl() function converts the unsigned integer hostlong  from  host
   byte order to network byte order.
....
```

Comment: I'm using these in implementation of hash functions, so it's performance sensitive - it's important that this disappear on architectures it's not needed. So i think it's either highly optimisable inlines or guard every use of them with macros. I'd prefer to go the inline route.

Comment: I also prefer inlines. Perhaps I should only suggest using the naming style.  These are historic names to be found in many applications.  I'm sure I have seen the implementations of these macros ... and it is relatively easy to use -E options.  On my Ubuntu 15.10, I can look at "/usr/include/netinet/in.h"